# how to insert a phrase after a word with sed in mac

Tags: macos, bash, bash-scripting

I have the following code:

```
sed  -i  "/#alias/a alias ll='ls -laGh'" /etc/zshrc
sed  -i  "/#alias/a alias l='ls -l'" /etc/zshrc
```

in the file /etc/zshrc I have:

```
#alias
```

but when executing the code it throws me the following error:

```
sed: 1: "/etc/zshrc": invalid command code z
```

I do not understand what happens

should be:

```
#alias
alias ll='ls -laGh'
alias l='ls -l'
```

it does not serve me in a line:

```
#alias
alias ll='ls -laGh' alias l='ls -l'
```

Comment: What platform is this on? It looks like you're trying to use GNU `sed`'s `-i` syntax with bsd `sed` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456518/invalid-command-code-despite-escaping-periods-using-sed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux) on stackoverflow). I think you'll also have trouble with the `a` command's syntax (it's weird, check the `man` page).

Comment: mac............

Comment: If there is another way to do it, I can also do it.

Comment: Try adding a separating blank: `sed  -i  "/#alias/ a alias ll='ls -laGh'" /etc/zshrc`.

Comment: not work: invalid command code z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first is that the macOS version of `sed` requires an explicit argument to the `-i` option telling it what extension to use for the backup file; if you don't want a backup, you need to pass an empty argument after it (`sed -i '' ...`). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456518/invalid-command-code-despite-escaping-periods-using-sed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux) on stackoverflow.

The second problem is that the `a` command requires an escaped newline before the string to be added, and a newline after it. From the [`man` page]:

```
 [1addr]a\
 text    Write text to standard output immediately before each attempt to
         read a line of input, whether by executing the ``N'' function or
         by beginning a new cycle.
```

Taking both of these into account, this should do what you want:

```
sed -i '' "/#alias/a\\
alias ll='ls -laGh'
" /etc/zshrc
```

If you want to avoid explicit newlines in the command string, you can define `nl=$'\n'`, and then use `${nl}` instead of explicit newlines. If you want to add multiple lines at once, I'd tend to use a loop to construct a `sed` command that'll add all of them in a single go:

```
nl=$'\n'
sedcmd=""
for aliascmd in "alias ll='ls -laGh'" "alias l='ls -l'"; do
    sedcmd+="a\\${nl}${aliascmd}${nl};"
done
sed -i '' "/#alias/ { ${sedcmd} }" /etc/zshrc
```

Or, if you prefer run multiple commands:

```
nl=$'\n'
sed -i '' "/#alias/a\\${nl}alias ll='ls -laGh'${nl}" /etc/zshrc
sed -i '' "/#alias/a\\${nl}alias l='ls -l'${nl}" /etc/zshrc
```

If this last option still doesn't work, run `set -x` and then try it again. Assuming you're using zsh, you should see something a lot like this:

```
+zsh:10> sed -i '' $'/#alias/a\\nalias ll=\'ls -laGh\'\n' /etc/zshrc
+zsh:11> sed -i '' $'/#alias/a\\nalias l=\'ls -l\'\n' /etc/zshrc
```

(only the numbers in `+zsh:something` will be different, and there'll also be a lot of irrelevant stuff about updating the terminal cwd.) The only reason I can think of that this would put everything on one line is if the newline at the end of the `sed` command is missing:

```
+zsh:11> sed -i '' $'/#alias/a\\nalias l=\'ls -l\'\n' /etc/zshrc
                                                  ^^
                                          this bit here
```

BTW, use `set +x` to turn off the debug tracing.

Comment: It does not work for me it puts it in row mode: alias ll='ls -laGh'
alias l='ls -l'. I need it one below the other as in the example

Comment: @ortiga I'm not sure what you mean by "row mode", but check the update.

Comment: He inserts it all in one line such that: alias ll = 'ls -laGh' alias l = 'ls -l' and I need to put it one under the other

Comment: @ortiga That's very strange; it works fine when I test it. Are you missing the newline before the close quote in the first version?

Comment: The second version of the for does not work because I have to do checks and the first one puts it in a row in a row

Comment: I have edited the question, take a look please

Comment: not work : + sed -i '' '/#alias/a\
\nalias ll='\''ls -laGh'\''\n' zshrc  He keeps adding it to me on the same line

Comment: something happens on mac

Comment: workkkkkkkkkk :))))))) thanks